# How do you use a function to create an Object with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, class, object, methods

Im doing a course in JavaScript. Im at the "Objects and classes" chapter, and I do not know how to solve some assignements in my homework.
The first exercise is like this

```
function createCat(name,age){
//Create a new object with the property "name" and the value defined by the argument "name".
//Add a new property to the object with the name "age" and use the value defined by the argument"age"
//Add a methos (function) called meow that returns the string "Meow"!
}
```

And this is what im trying

```
 function createCat(name,age){
      var Cat={};
        Cat.Name=name;
        Cat.Age=age;
        Cat.meow=function(){return "Meow!"};
        return Cat;
     }
```

Im testing the function loading the script in an index.html file, opening that file in a browser and then testing the functions in the web Console. I run the function and there is no problem. Then, I test if the Cat object was returned by writing Cat.Name in the console, which results in an error. The same thing happens when I call the function in a line of code below and then try to access the properties of the Object. The error reads "ReferenceError: Cat is not defined". What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A cleaner way to do this is to leave out the `let Cat = {}` part entirely. You can use the function itself to create a `Cat` object.

```
function Cat(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.meow = () => console.log("Meow!");
}

let myCat = new Cat("Waldorf", 16)
let anotherCat = new Cat("Statler", 12)

myCat.meow()
console.log(anotherCat.name)
```

Comment: I agree this is a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your function returns Cat, but this is only a name in function scope. In order to use that name out of the function, you need to do this:

```js
function createCat(name, age) {
        var cat = {};
        cat.Name = name;
        cat.Age = age;
        cat.meow = () => "Meow!";
        return cat;
}

let Cat = createCat("mist", 16);

console.log(Cat)
```

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because `Cat` is only defined within the scope of your function. To define `Cat` globally, use `window.Cat` instead of `var Cat`:

```js
function createCat(name, age) {
  window.Cat = {};
  Cat.Name = name;
  Cat.Age = age;
  Cat.meow = function() {
    return "Meow!"
  };
  return Cat;
}

console.log(Cat.Name);
```

Comment: This answer is actually not correct, because now the function will overwrite the window.Cat every time the function is called...

Comment: This is the only way you would be able to call Cat outside of the function. It is not a requirement (as per the exercise requirements) but it is the main reason the OP is getting the error.

Comment: The OP's function returns a cat, so it makes more sense to store that returned cat in a variable. For example: `let cat = createCat("Jonesy", 10)`. That way the cat is available in the global scope AND you can have more than one different cat.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get your Cat when you type on the console `Cat.name` you have to declare it globally like so:

```js
function createCat(name, age) {
  return {
    name: name,
    age: age,
    meow: function() {
      return "Meow!"
    },
  };
}
```

`window.Cat = createCat('name', 2);`

Then you can access your Cat globally.

You could also assign the Cat to a variable on the browser console and access it through `Cat.name` like so:

`const Cat = createCat('name', 2);`